# Why do I have so many CSS files?

Tags: 7, theming

Hi i am  running from issue in drupal 7 site 
-problem 
There is lots of css   files come 
in sites/defaults/files/css

```
    -uyqtwuetuwet.css
-uyqtwuetuwet.zip
    -khkjhkhk.css
 -khkjhkhk.zip
```

there is lots of files of this kind

I only use style.css
And file url come like this
[image]
I dont know how they come
Also there is zip file are made on server 
Same issue on the  Js 
It causes site performance issue 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to check 'aggregate css' and 'aggregate js' on /admin/config/development/performance? This should make things considerably faster. Also the css in the image seems to be part of a theme called 'market'.

Comment: are you talking about what comes after 'style.css' in the url .  If so it's not a problem. I think it's for Drupal to make sure you're using a current version of the CSS file, and not an outdated cached version.

Comment: @deejay  No actually on sites default folder  these is css and js files come with name style.css@1asasyq7 like this way and size of folder comes 40-50 mb

Comment: @Zuzuesque yes i tried  but issue  is from where  js and css file  are generated

Comment: They're generated by Drupal. They aren't deleted straight away because people with cached pages still have references to them, and it would mess those up. They'll be deleted in due course on a cron job. As an aside, if the hosting you have makes you consider 50mb of used space to be a "performance issue", you should switch to a better hosting provider

Comment: I think the module AdvAgg could help with the performance as it would affect these Drupal-generated css ...